# Symfony/Process fails with exception

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to execute standalone chromedriver for linux with the Symfony/Process component. Here is the folder structure of the project:

```
 .
 ├── bin
 │   └── chromedriver-linux
 ├── composer.json
 ├── index.php
 └── vendor
```

In `index.php` this is the code that I'm trying to execute:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new Process(
    [realpath(__DIR__.'/bin/chromedriver-linux')], null, ['DISPLAY' => ':0']
);

$process->start();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new \Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

Yet it got even worse. Now there is no error output, it just throws an Exception like:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The command "'/home/vagrant/Code/development/test-project/bin/chromedriver-linux'" failed. Exit Code: () Working directory: /home/vagrant/Code/development/dusk-2.0 Output: ================ Error Output: ================ in /home/vagrant/Code/development/test-project/index.php on line 14
```

Comment: Perhaps also post the output ..

Comment: @lostbyte Did you try running `chromedriver-linux` from command line? If so, what did you type in and what was the output? It will make it easier to understand why the process fails

Comment: @dbrumann I used ./chromedriver-linux inside \bin directory and it worked fine. This is the output: `Starting ChromeDriver 2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.`

Comment: I would recommend starting with the simplest approach for the Process as well and then add parameters later on. So try: `new Process('chromedriver-linux', __DIR__ . '/bin');` and see if it works

Comment: Getting the same error with no output.